# Correctly reference the class and class members in multi-tier application

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I am a little confused with an asp.net application, as I am unable to build the project and get following error:

`Error  46  The type 'App.DAL' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'App.DAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. ....`

Basically the Solution has 3 Projects:

1. App.DAL
2. App.BLL //references DAL
3. App.Project //references BLL

Here, in DAL, I have a public class called Student

```
namespace App.DAL
{
   public class Student
   {
    public Student(){} //Default Constructor

    private Int16 _StudentID = -1;

    // Public Variables
    public Int16 StudentID
    {
        get { return _StudentID; }
        set { _StudentID= value; }
    }

    public Student MyMethod()
    {
        // return Object of Student Type;
    }
   }
}
```

My App.BLL class is:

```
namespace App.BLL
{
   [Serializable]
   public class Student: DAL.Student
   {
    public Student(){} //Default Constructor

    // Public Variables
    public Int16 StudentID_BLL
    {
        get { return this.StudentID; }
        set { this.StudentID= value; }
    }

    public Student MyMethod_BLL()
    {
        // return Object of Student Type;
    }
   }
}
```

Now in my App.Project, I'd like to access the `Student` type object to serialize it and return as JSON using webservice, but unable to bind correctly. I am new to accessing class and objects in multi-layered projects.

Comment: Did you add a reference to assembly App.DAL as it said in the error ?

Comment: Its already mentioned that `App.DAL is` referenced by `App.BLL` and `App.BLL` is referenced by `App.Project`

Comment: No, you should add App.DAL reference to the App.Project

Comment: No, that is not possible, I have to keep that abstraction, so that `App.DAL` is not referenced directly by `App.Project`, and I guess **that** is causing the problem, but I don't have a solution for it.

Comment: You cannot keep abstraction with this way, change your objects as Upendra wrote (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20541655/2372659), create an interface for your DAL class in another project or in App.BLL, use this interface in App.BLL. Then use manual injection or a DI tool to inject App.DAL as your interface

Comment: And if you don't about DI, you can search for Castle Windsor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating Student class 2 times, one is in DAL and another in BLL. Actually it is business object class which should move from/to DAL and BLL methods. **Actually you need to create new project for business objects (entities/models).**

Add reference of BO project in all DAL, BLL and web projects. Add reference of DAL in BLL and reference of BLL in web project. From web project, call all methods of BLL class to get or save data in database.

For example Student business class will be like :

```
public class Student
{
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}
```

DAL class will be like

```
public class StudentDAL
{
   public List<Student> GetAll()
   {
     -----
   }

   public Student GetById(long studentId)
   {
     -----
   }
}
```

You can make static methods in BLL class like

```
public class StudentBLL
{
   public static List<Student> GetAll()
   {
     using (StudentDAL studentDAL = new StudentDAL())
     {
         return studentDAL.GetAll();
     }
   }

   public static Student GetById(long studentId)
   {
      using (StudentDAL studentDAL = new StudentDAL())
     {
        return studentDAL.GetById(studentId);
     }
   }
}
```

From web, you can call it by

```
List<Student> studentList = StudentBLL.GetAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the `Student` class in the web project then you need to add a reference to the assembly in which is defined.

A best practice is to add a new layer, named "`App.Entities`" or "`App.Models`", that should contain all your business entities. Then you will add references to it from the DAL, BLL and Web projects:

1. App.Entities
2. App.DAL (references Entities)
3. App.BLL (references Entites and DAL)
4. App.Project (references Entities and BLL but doesn't references the DAL directly)

Using this approach you will remove the necessity of referencing the DAL from the Web project, so the web app knows that will receive a Student object but does not know that the Student is coming from a database, a Web Service or another data provider.